# Python: Returning values of matrix that are in a specific range, range is given as a tuple(from, to)

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, spyder

School problem:

Define a 2 parameter (inputs) function that will return the average value for elements that are within a given range. Range is given as a tuple.

I must compose 2 functions:

1 is using loops;

2 is using operations.

```
def mygmean(array,tuple):   # Determines values inside and outside a specified range
    """
    Determines values inside and outside a specified range.
    """
    
    import numpy as np
    incluided = []
    excluded = []
    
    
    for k in range(0, array.shape[0]):
        for i in range(0, array.shape[1]):
            if array[k,i] < tuple[0] or array[k,i] > tuple[-1]:
                excluded.append(array[k,i])
                pass
            else:
                incluided.append(array[k,i])
    final_geomean = np.prod(incluided)**(1/len(incluided))
        
    print(array)
    print(incluided)
    print(excluded)
    print(final_geomean)
    return(final_geomean,excluded)
```

Edit:
Solved Part #1 by writing:

```
def mygmean(array,t):   # Determines values inside and outside a specified range
    """
    Determines values inside and outside a specified range.
    """
    
    import numpy as np
    incluided = []
    excluded = []
    
    for k in range(0, array.shape[0]):
        for i in range(0, array.shape[1]):
            if array[k,i] < t[0] or array[k,i] > t[-1]:
                excluded.append(array[k,i])
                pass
            else:
                incluided.append(array[k,i])
    final_geomean = np.prod(incluided)**(1/len(incluided))

    return(final_geomean,excluded)
```

Console input:

```
mygmean(np.array([[2,4],[-9,3],[6,-2],[8,1],[12,8]]),(0,10)))
```

Desired output:

```
(3.684369762785971, array([-9, -2, 12]))
```

Comment: Is `array` a `list` (i.e. 1D) or a `list` of lists (i.e. 2D)?

Comment: Do not call your parameter `tuple`.  That hides the Python type of the same name.  Maybe `target` would be better.

Comment: @not_speshal Not sure what you mean.
array is given as: np.array([[2,4],[-9,3],[6,-2],[8,1],[12,8]])

Comment: @TimRoberts good call

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized (i.e. non-loop) version would be to use `nympy.where` and `numpy.nanmean`:

```
import numpy as np
def mygmean(array, t):
    return np.nanmean(np.where((array>=t[0]) & (array<t[1]), array, np.nan))

# example
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
mygmean(a, (2,5))
# 3.0
```

*NB. I assumed here included lower bound and excluded upper bound*